# How to display related data in html with Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new to Angular 7. I am trying to display a product's color on html side with Angular 7 but I couldn't succeed.

My tables are like below;

**Product**

Id

Name

**Color**

Id

Name

**ProductColorRelation**

Id

ProductId

ColorId

In product.component.ts file, product variable is declared

```
public product: Product;
```

On Product screen, I am trying to display product's colors with code below

```
{{ product.ProductColorRelations[0].Name }}
```

But it doesn't display the color's name. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Navigation doesn't work in Typescript'

Comment: Please `Console.log(product)` and share

Comment: @AdritaSharma, Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: console.. lowecase c

Comment: I just understood what you mean. product is oblect is filled as expected.

Comment: @ArifYILMAZ  use it in angular component ts code and show us a sample data in variable `product`

Comment: Type it in typescript

Comment: @ArifYILMAZ   seems like you need to loop the products  using `*ngFor` to get each products or just use `{{ product[0]?.ProductColorRelations[0]?.Color?.Name }}`

Comment: Assuming that `product` is that 0th index which is showed in the screenshot.
As the `Name` is in the `Color` object:  `{{ product.ProductColorRelations[0].Color.Name }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is an array of products you can do this the following way

```
{{ products[0]?.ProductColorRelations[0]?.Color?.Name }}
```

But the best option is to loop through each product using `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products">
   {{ product?.ProductColorRelations[0]?.Color?.Name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
product.ProductColorRelations[0].Color.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

As color's name is in colors array you need to write in html like this:

```
{{ product.ProductColorRelations[0].Color.Name }}
```

and it'll give you the perfect result.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is not clear if printed console belongs to the product itself.

There are two ways to make sure the same. In your HTML you can write something like this to make sure what data is present in the product.

```
{{ product | json }}
```

It will help you to see what is coming in your product object.

If it is a product object mentioned in the console then,

```
{{ product?.ProductColorRelations[0]?.Color?.Name }}
```